# Hiding the calling function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to write an application that runs some mixed JavaScript code. What I mean by "mixed", is that some of the code is mine, and some is external.
My code will be calling some external code, but I would like to conceal the call stack. In other words, in a scenario like this:

```
// my code
function myFunc()
{
   extFunc();
}

// external code
function extFunc()
{
   if (arguments.callee.caller == null)
   {
        console.log("okay");
   }
}
```

I would like the last "if" to evaluate true. Can it be done in plain JavaScript?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you want to do this?  Is it some "security" concern?

Comment: You could it call it in a `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(extFunc, 0);`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, it is for reasons of security. I'm sorry, but I cannot elaborate...

Answer (score 2):

Functions defined in strict mode does not have `caller` property.

See following code in console:

```
function a() {
    return arguments.callee.caller;
}
(function b(){
    return a()
}()) // this expression returns b function
var c = (function strict(){
  'use strict';
  return function cInner() {
     return a();
  }
})();

c(); // Throw TypeError: access to strict mode caller function is censored
```

More about strict mode - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: Adding `"use strict";` to `myFunc()` seems to work in my tests.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to call the method async:

```
function myFunc()
{
   setTimeout(function(){ extFunc(); }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Good idea, but this doesn't *quite* work.  `setTimeout` will run the anonymous function, which will call `extFunc`.  The `arguments.callee.caller` won't be `null`.  For it to be `null`, you'd have to do `setTimeout(extFunc, 0);`.